# importing header.html into every html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, navbar

I want to use AngularJS to include a header in every html i use. here is the header.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container-fluid1">
    <div class="navbar-header" id="websiteName">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Richazon</a>
    </div>
    <div id="theLinks">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Navbar Color <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu1">
                    <li class="greenBg"><a href="#">NB1</a></li>
                    <li id="greenBg"><a href="#">NB2</a></li>
                    <li id="greenBg"><a href="#">NB3</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Page 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2.0.0 </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2.0.1 </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="AngularListRemoval.html">AngularJS List Removal </a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Page 3 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3.0.0 </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3.0.1 </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3.0.3 </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3.0.4 </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3.0.5 </a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3.0.6 </a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

in my index1.html file I have this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```

then inside the body tag

```
<div appheader></div>
```

i understand this question has already been asked, hence my implementation. but i keep getting this error in the console: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)`

this is the code at the top of my index1.html file which might be causing issues:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href="css/index1.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and here is my main.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('appheader', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'header.html'
    };
  });
```

Comment: In the index, you are linking angular script twice (version 1.3.14 then version 1.0.1). And bootstrap is also linked twice

Comment: templates shouldn't include `<head>` and `<body>`

Comment: removed these tags, still doesn't make the header visible

Comment: the **header.html** should only contain the `nav` element. Do you really need a custom directive? Use `ng-include` instead.

Comment: You must come from a language like PHP where you could include a whole template page but It's not a proper way to proceed with Angular. If you wan't to make dynamic HTML template with javascript use Jade or Hogan, but Angular must be used as a front framework. Element in your pages may be included but you can't append a whole page with `<html>` and `<body>` tags unless if it's in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your main.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('appheader', function() {
  return {
  templateUrl: 'header.html'
  };
});
```

you need to create module

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
```